# Where can I get Eagle Species images Dataset?

Tags: data-request, images

### List of Eagle Species

Eagles are large birds of prey which are members of the bird family Accipitridae and belong to several genera that are not necessarily closely related to each other. Most of the more than 60 species occur in Eurasia and Africa. Outside this area, just two species can be found in the United States and Canada, nine more in Central and South America, and three in Australia.

> Looking for the Eagle species Images Dataset for Deep Learning & AI Research purpose.

Below are listed all the members of the eagle family.

[Collected From](https://www.birdlife.org/worldwide/news/list-eagle-species)

```
White-bellied Sea-eagle Haliaeetus leucogaster  LC
Sanford's Sea-eagle Haliaeetus sanfordi VU
African Fish-eagle Haliaeetus vocifer   LC
Madagascar Fish-eagle Haliaeetus vociferoides   CR
Pallas's Fish-eagle Haliaeetus leucoryphus  VU
White-tailed Eagle Haliaeetus albicilla LC
Bald Eagle Haliaeetus leucocephalus LC
Steller's Sea-eagle Haliaeetus pelagicus    VU
Lesser Fish-eagle Ichthyophaga humilis  NT
Grey-headed Fish-eagle Ichthyophaga ichthyaetus 

Snake-eagles
Short-toed Snake-eagle Circaetus gallicus   LC
Black-chested Snake-eagle Circaetus pectoralis  LC
Beaudouin's Snake-eagle Circaetus beaudouini    VU
Brown Snake-eagle Circaetus cinereus    LC
Southern Banded Snake-eagle Circaetus fasciolatus   NT
Western Banded Snake-eagle Circaetus cinerascens    LC
Crested Serpent-eagle Spilornis cheela  LC
South Nicobar Serpent-eagle Spilornis klossi    NT
Kinabalu Serpent-eagle Spilornis kinabaluensis  VU
Sulawesi Serpent-eagle Spilornis rufipectus LC
Philippine Serpent-eagle Spilornis holospilus   LC
Andaman Serpent-eagle Spilornis elgini  NT
Congo Serpent-eagle Dryotriorchis spectabilis   LC
Madagascar Serpent-eagle Eutriorchis astur  EN
Bateleur Terathopius ecaudatus
Black-chested Buzzard-eagle Geranoaetus melanoleucus    LC
Black Solitary Eagle Buteogallus solitarius NT
Crowned Solitary Eagle Buteogallus coronatus    EN
Crested Eagle Morphnus guianensis   NT
Harpy Eagle Harpia harpyja  NT
Papuan Eagle Harpyopsis novaeguineae    VU
Philippine Eagle Pithecophaga jefferyi  CR
Black Eagle Ictinaetus malaiensis   LC
Lesser Spotted Eagle Clanga pomarina    LC
Indian Spotted Eagle Clanga hastata VU
Greater Spotted Eagle Clanga clanga VU
Tawny Eagle Aquila rapax    LC
Steppe Eagle Aquila nipalensis  EN
Spanish Imperial Eagle Aquila adalberti VU
Eastern Imperial Eagle Aquila heliaca   VU
Gurney's Eagle Aquila gurneyi   NT
Golden Eagle Aquila chrysaetos  LC
Wedge-tailed Eagle Aquila audax LC
Verreaux's Eagle Aquila verreauxii  LC
Wahlberg's Eagle Aquila wahlbergi   LC
Bonelli's Eagle Aquila fasciata LC
African Hawk-eagle Aquila spilogaster   LC
Booted Eagle Hieraaetus pennatus    LC
Little Eagle Hieraaetus morphnoides LC
Pygmy Eagle Hieraaetus weiskei  LC
Ayres's Hawk-eagle Hieraaetus ayresii   LC
Martial Eagle Polemaetus bellicosus NT
Long-crested Eagle Lophaetus occipitalis    LC
Cassin's Hawk-eagle Aquila africana LC
Black Hawk-eagle Spizaetus tyrannus LC
Black-and-white Hawk-eagle Spizaetus melanoleucus   LC
Ornate Hawk-eagle Spizaetus ornatus NT
Black-and-chestnut Eagle Spizaetus isidori  EN
Crowned Hawk-eagle Stephanoaetus coronatus  NT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iNaturalist is another good place to find photographs of biological organisms. You can easily filter for images with specified levels of copyright. This link will get you to a page with observations of genus Haliaeetus in the public domain (copyrights waived by the photographer under the [CC0 designation](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)):

https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?photo_license=CC0&taxon_id=5303

To download a photograph, click on the observation, then hover the mouse over the photograph and click on the `i` symbol to get to the page for that photograph. There you can download the photograph in various sizes (small, medium, large or original). Each observation can have more than one photograph.

For other genera of eagles, replace `taxon_id=5303` with

- `taxon_id=5068` for genus *Aquila*
- `taxon_id=5232` for genus *Buteogallus*
- `taxon_id=5239` for genus *Circaetus*
- `taxon_id=5398` for genus *Dryotriorchis*
- `taxon_id=5385` for genus *Eutriorchis*
- `taxon_id=5320` for genus *Harpia*
- `taxon_id=5387` for genus *Harpyopsis*
- `taxon_id=5148` for genus *Hieraaetus*
- `taxon_id=5334` for genus *Lophaetus*
- `taxon_id=5383` for genus *Morphnus*
- `taxon_id=5343` for genus *Polemaetus*
- `taxon_id=5156` for genus *Spilornis*
- `taxon_id=5289` for genus *Spizaetus*
- `taxon_id=5322` for genus *Stephanoaetus*
- `taxon_id=5230` for genus *Terathopius*

For photographs with some copyright restrictions, replace `photo_license=CC0` with `photo_license=` plus any of the following:

- `CC-BY`
- `CC-BY-NC`
- `CC-BY-SA`
- `CC-BY-ND`
- `CC-BY-NC-SA`
- `CC-BY-NC-ND`

For bulk downloads, use the [export query builder](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/export).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to simply searching sources like Google Images or Getty Images, the [Global Biodiversity Information Facility (GBIF)](https://www.gbif.org/) has a gallery feature that allows you to search for images of an organism.  Note that (1) images are user contributed, therefore the licensing is determined by the contributor, and (2) are not hosted by GBIF directly.  Make sure your use of these images is consistent with the license under which they have been released and that attribution is given when necessary.  See some details on how users contribute images to GBIF occurrence data [here](https://data-blog.gbif.org/post/gbif-multimedia/).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could check the ebird application, maybe you can get eagle datasets: https://ebird.org/home
Regards