# Where can I get Wild Animals population(World Wide) Dataset per region?

Tags: data-request, animals

#### Where can I get all Animals population(World Wide) dataset worldwide as per region yearly??

> Looking for the Wild Animals populations Dataset for Machine Learning & AI Research purpose.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  Do you mean total population sizes of all animal species worldwide, or per region?  Your examples are all predator mammals.  Are you interested in ladybugs and parrotfish too?

Comment: Updated Question. Population sizes of all animals yearly

Comment: Not sure this will completely address your need, but did you check out [GBIF occurrences](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search)?  I recall suggesting this source in [another one of your questions](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16012/7031).